# Having trouble displaying contacts with special characters on TableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've got a problem populating my table view. Currently, I'm creating a phone book. This phone book will simply contain contacts that are fetched with the help of the Contacts framework. These contacts are separated into sections alphabetically.

Sadly, although my contacts are well displayed alphabetically on the table view, my app crashes because I'm not taking into account all the possibilities a contact can have in his given name and last name. (Assumes standard English language alphabet with no diacritics, symbols, numbers or anything else)

I've am stuck on trying to implement ways on how to make sure emojis, different languages and special characters are taken into account. I have not found any good solution to it.

Let me run you through my code to enhance my explanation:

First of all, I created a ExpandableNames struct:

```
struct ExpandableNames{
    var isExpanded: Bool
    var contacts: [Contact]
}

struct Contact {
    let contact: CNContact
}
```

Where isExpanded was simply a state representing whether the section where that contact is, is Expanded or closed.

Now, I've created these two arrays to populate my rows and sections:

```
var array2d = Array<[Contact]>(repeating: [Contact](), count: 27)
var twoDimensionalArray = [ExpandableNames]()
```

**NOTE**: 27 is the number of letters in the alphabet plus a section for the numbers, emojis and other special characters.

Once I've got this set up, I created a function to fetch contacts. This is where everything starts to get a bit complicated.

In the following code, I've commented everything to be as specific as I could. I have taken into account all the ASCII characters as well as every possible possibility of the contact's name information.

```
 private func fetchContacts(){

        let store = CNContactStore()

        store.requestAccess(for: (.contacts)) { (granted, err) in
            if let err = err{
                print("Failed to request access",err)
                return
            }

            if granted {
                print("Access granted")

                let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
                let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
                var contacts = [Contact]()

                do{

                    //var favoritableContacts = [FavoritableContact]()
                    try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stopPointerIfYouWantToStopEnumerating) in

                        contacts.append(Contact(contact: contact))

                    })

                    //Find the ascii value for "A" to use as your base
                    let aAscii = Int("A".unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value })[0])  //This returns 65, btw, so you could also just hardcode

                    //MARK: Checking every possibility that the user can Input for the names.

                    //Go through your original array, find the first letter of each contact's family name, and append to the correct array
                    contacts.forEach { (contact) in

                        //FAMILY NAMES ONLY WITH GIVEN NAMES
                        if contact.contact.familyName != "" && contact.contact.givenName != ""{

                            //Get the ascii value for the first letter of the family name
                            let firstCharacterFamilyName = Int(contact.contact.familyName.prefix(1).uppercased().unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value })[0])
                            // - prefix(1) means take the first character of the family name
                            // - Uppercase makes sure even that even if the chracter is lowercased, it will be compared to A since the lowercased will become Upper cased.
                            // - A view of a string’s contents as a collection of Unicode scalar values
                            // - filter all the characters that arent ASCII.
                            // - map will loop over the collection and returns an array containing the results of applying a mapping or transform function to each item.
                            // - [0] will get the first value of the array


                            //Making sure it is between A and Z
                            if (firstCharacterFamilyName >= 65 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 90){
                                //Append to the array for this letter by subtracting the ascii value for "A" from the ascii value for the uppercased version of this letter.
                                self.array2d[firstCharacterFamilyName - aAscii].append(contact)

                                //Checking for space ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /
                                //Checking for numbers
                                //Checking for : ; < = > ? @
                            }else if(firstCharacterFamilyName >= 32 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 64){
                                self.array2d[26].append(contact)
                               //Checking for space [ \ ] ^ _ `
                            }else if(firstCharacterFamilyName >= 91 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 96){
                                self.array2d[26].append(contact)
                                //Checking for space { | } ~
                            }else if(firstCharacterFamilyName >= 123 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 126){
                                self.array2d[26].append(contact)
                            }

                        //GIVEN NAMES ONLY WITHOUT FAMILY NAMES
                        }else if contact.contact.givenName != "" && contact.contact.familyName == ""{

                            //Get the ascii value for the first letter of the given name
                            let firstCharacterGivenName = Int(contact.contact.givenName.prefix(1).uppercased().unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value })[0])

                            //Making sure it is between A and Z
                            if (firstCharacterGivenName >= 65 && firstCharacterGivenName <= 90){
                                //Append to the array for this letter by subtracting the ascii value for "A" from the ascii value for the uppercased version of this letter.
                                self.array2d[firstCharacterGivenName - aAscii].append(contact)

                                //Checking for space ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /
                                //Checking for numbers
                                //Checking for : ; < = > ? @
                            }else if(firstCharacterGivenName >= 32 && firstCharacterGivenName <= 64){
                                self.array2d[26].append(contact)
                                //Checking for space [ \ ] ^ _ `
                            }else if(firstCharacterGivenName >= 91 && firstCharacterGivenName <= 96){
                                self.array2d[26].append(contact)
                                //Checking for space { | } ~
                            }else if(firstCharacterGivenName >= 123 && firstCharacterGivenName <= 126){
                                self.array2d[26].append(contact)
                            }

                        //GIVEN NAMES ONLY WITHOUT FAMILY NAMES
                        }else if contact.contact.familyName != "" && contact.contact.givenName == ""{

                            //Get the ascii value for the first letter of the given name
                            let firstCharacterFamilyName = Int(contact.contact.familyName.prefix(1).uppercased().unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value })[0])

                            //Making sure it is between A and Z
                            if (firstCharacterFamilyName >= 65 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 90){
                                //Append to the array for this letter by subtracting the ascii value for "A" from the ascii value for the uppercased version of this letter.
                                self.array2d[firstCharacterFamilyName - aAscii].append(contact)

                                //Checking for space ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /
                                //Checking for numbers
                                //Checking for : ; < = > ? @
                            }else if(firstCharacterFamilyName >= 32 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 64){
                                self.array2d[26].append(contact)
                                //Checking for space [ \ ] ^ _ `
                            }else if(firstCharacterFamilyName >= 91 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 96){
                                self.array2d[26].append(contact)
                                //Checking for space { | } ~
                            }else if(firstCharacterFamilyName >= 123 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 126){
                                self.array2d[26].append(contact)
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    for index in self.array2d.indices{

                        //For console visual
                        let startingValue = Int(("A" as UnicodeScalar).value) // 65
                        print(Character(UnicodeScalar(index + startingValue)!))
                        print("Number of items at \(index): \(self.array2d[index].count)")


                        let names = ExpandableNames(isExpanded: true, contacts: self.array2d[index])

                        //If there is no element in that index then dont do anything. If there is then append names to twoDimensionalArray
                        if self.array2d[index].count != 0{
                            self.twoDimensionalArray.append(names)
                        }

                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }



                } catch let err{
                    print("Failed to enumerate contacts", err)
                }


            }else{
                print("Access denied")
            }
        }

    }
```

The rest is simple UI configurations and making sure I add the right sections and rows to the tableview. When I run my code, it simply looks like this:

[image: Populated tableview from contacts]

As soon as I add a emoji to a contact on their given name or family name, the app crashes at:

```
let firstCharacterFamilyName = Int(contact.contact.familyName.prefix(1).uppercased().unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value })[0])
```

Which makes sense. Now this means that I might be over complicating myself on the way I am checking for the first letters of given names and family names. I've tried different approaches but this one was the closest one to success.

Comment: Just a suggestion, try converting your emoji to string through this code : https://pastebin.com/qxtWuYNd . Then use regex to remove the part in {"emo ji info"} and then sort the list.

Comment: Just as an aside... do you realize that the block of code "//GIVEN NAMES ONLY WITHOUT FAMILY NAMES" is repeated twice?

Comment: Sorry I see now it is only the comment that is repeated.  Another thing is that in your if {} else if {} else if {} logic, you do not include a final else{}... so you could have conditions that fall through and you would never know. This is useful for debugging... You could say something like.. if {} else if {} else if {} else {print(We have a case that is not accounted for)}.  I'm still working on a solution...

Comment: oh yes I’ll modify that! Thank youu

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your goal is to sort all contacts *only* alphabetically, and to put ALL non-alphabetically-sortable contacts into "section 26,"

I offer the following solution... probably not the best, obviously, because your problem also has to do with overall design.  But maybe it will get you thinking in new ways... and it gets rid of the crash.

The main problem in your code is that

```
let firstCharacterFamilyName = Int(contact.contact.familyName.prefix(1).uppercased().unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value })[0])
```

is only checking for the condition where "prefix(1)" IS ASCII... and does not check or know how to handle the case where is is NOT ASCII.

So... before we allow that line of code to execute, we need to make sure that we are dealing with a sortable contact (starts with a-z, or A-Z).

First... add the following function to your code:

```
func charIsALetter(input: Character) -> Bool {


    if (!(input >= "a" && input <= "z") && !(input >= "A" && input <= "Z") ) {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true}
}
```

This will allow you to check whether any individual Character is a letter a-z or A-Z.

Then... you can use that function in your code like this:

```
    // get the first letter like you normally do
    let firstCharacter = contact.contact.givenName.prefix(1) 

    //
    let result = charIsALetter(input: Character(String(firstCharacter)))

    if result == true {
        let firstCharacterGivenName = Int(firstCharacter.uppercased().unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value })[0])

        // do all your normal ASCII sorting here
    }

    else {

        // put this contact into SECTION 26

    }
```

Now you do not need all this:

```
//Checking for space ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /
//Checking for numbers
//Checking for : ; < = > ? @
}else if(firstCharacterFamilyName >= 32 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 64){
self.array2d[26].append(contact)
//Checking for space [ \ ] ^ _ `
}else if(firstCharacterFamilyName >= 91 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 96){
self.array2d[26].append(contact)
//Checking for space { | } ~
}else if(firstCharacterFamilyName >= 123 && firstCharacterFamilyName <= 126){
self.array2d[26].append(contact)
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hey man! thx for your time. Your code crashes when it reads the character é. It reads it as a true value. Therefore it goes in the if statements and crashes at the same point as mine.

Comment: well... I hope you are closer to a solution anyway.  I think if you can break down the line "let firstCharacterFamilyName = Int(contact.contact.familyName.prefix(1).uppercased().unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value })[0])" into smaller parts... and print the value to the console for each part, you will see why it's crashing and how to solve it. I don't know exactly why it is crashing though sorry... I only know that it has to do with the part "filter.... etc" onward from there... and it's an index out of range error.  Why don't you just map everything even if it's not ascii?

Comment: You could just create charIsASCII() function and replace the charIsALetter() function with it.  That would do exactly what your code does but without the crash.

Comment: This is what led me to understand that line of code:  https://youtu.be/4VoSeyy6KRc?list=PLPA-ayBrweUz32NSgNZdl0_QISw-f12Ai&t=2636

Comment: I’m going to try it ! if it becomes to complicated, I will end up using the contactsUI man.. Because if I have users from all over the world then I’m gonna have to sort all characters alphabetically for every language .. Seems rough. I’m wondering if I could instead fetch the contacts by section.. Like in the contacts app, you have the first section where the familyNames start with the letter A. It would be much easier instead of sorting it myself. I’d simply just append it to the arrays. Anyways, if you know anything about this let me know! thank you SOO much for your time dude

Comment: You're welcome.  You might also find this interesting: https://youtu.be/4VoSeyy6KRc?list=PLPA-ayBrweUz32NSgNZdl0_QISw-f12Ai&t=3244